# HTML Form Not POSTing? Has name field?

Tags: php, html, forms

I feel like an absolute moron posting this question, but I'm completely serious, I officially have NO idea why this form isn't posting. I've gone from using AJAX to display information inputted to simple submit-redirect-grab Post data in PHP to $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] trying to get the information to JUST POST, and it won't. Most of the people asking this question have had their answers revealed as "You need a name field" or "Your javascript is the issue" but I have a name field and I am no longer using javascript. I am utterly and completely confused.

For reference, I'm using PHPStorm and a Local server to test this out. I just logged on fresh today, saved the project, ran it for the first times today, made sure it wasn't just a sort of cached project, and it doesn't appear to have anything with old data.

Please don't mind if some of the form syntax is messy, I just want this darn post to work so I can move on to the meat of what I'm trying to make. Also there is no stylesheet currently, it's mostly empty apart from

```
.id {
    height: 100px;
}
```

**Also** none of the form fields are required, you really only need to enter information into one. I've got it doing a var_dump just so I can see all of the form post data, and it's brilliantly not working. I did have it echoing out something in PHP along the lines of "Done!" to show php is being read, and I also had it attempting to echo $_POST["modelnumber"] just to see that. Nope.

index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    Model Number:<br>
    <input type="text" id="mod" name="modelnumber"><br><br>
    Amazon Item?<br>
    <input type="radio" id="amazonItemY" name="amazonItem" value="yes"> Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" id="amazonItemN" name="amazonItem" value="no" checked> No<br><br>
    Item name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="intName" name="itemName"><br><br>
    Item Description:<br>
    <input type="text" id="internetDescription" name="description"><br><br>
    Brand:<br>
    <input type="text" id="brand" name="itemBrand"><br><br>
    Manufacturer:<br>
    <input type="text" id="manufacturer" name="manName"><br><br>
    Website category:<br>
    <input type="text" id="cmcategory" name="category"><br><br>
    Clearance?<br>
    <input type="radio" id="clearanceY" name="clearance" value="yes"> Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" id="clearanceN" name="clearance" value="no" checked> No<br><br>
    Competitor Price: (leave empty if not clearance)<br>
    <input type="text" id="competitorPrice" name="compPrice"><br><br>
    School price:<br>
    <input type="text" id="catStdPrice" name="schoolPrice"><br><br>
    Dealer price:<br>
    <input type="text" id="dealerStdPrice" name="dealerPrice"><br><br>
    Website price(normal):<br>
    <input type="text" id="intCsiPrice" name="webPrice"><br><br>
    Unit of Measure:<br>
    <input type="text" id="unitOfMeasure" name="uom"><br><br>
    UPC:<br>
    <input type="text" id="upc" name="upcNum"><br><br>
    Manufacturer Part Number:<br>
    <input type="text" id="mfgr_num" name="manfacNum"><br><br>
    Item Attribute:<br> <!--needs to be a dropdown-->
    <select id="attribute" name="attributes">
        <option value="(1593325)Baseball">Baseball</option>
        <option value="(1593326)Basketball">Basketball</option>
        <option value="(1593386)Boating + Paddling">Boating + Paddling</option>
        <option value="(1593314)Camping Hiking + Climbing">Camping_ Hiking + Climbing</option>
        <option value="(1610848)Cricket">Cricket</option>
        <option value="(1593313)Cycling">Cycling</option>
        <option value="(1593315)Equestrian">Equestrian</option>
        <option value="(1593318)Fishing">Fishing</option>
        <option value="(1593323)Football">Football</option>
        <option value="(1594100)General Sports Equipment + Accessories">General Sports Equipment + Accessories</option>
        <option value="(1593320)Golf">Golf</option>
        <option value="(1593319)Hunting + Archery">Hunting + Archery</option>
        <option value="(1593329)Ice + Roller Hockey">Ice + Roller Hockey</option>
        <option value="(1593327)Other Sports">Other Sports</option>
        <option value="(1593331)Personal Fitness">Personal Fitness</option>
        <option value="(1599122)Pool + Billiards">Pool + Billiards</option>
        <option value="(1593321)Rugby">Rugby</option>
        <option value="(1593317)Skateboarding + Rollerskating">Skateboarding + Rollerskating</option>
        <option value="(1593330)Ski + Snow">Ski + Snow</option>
        <option value="(1593322)Soccer">Soccer</option>
        <option value="(1593324)Softball">Softball</option>
        <option value="(1593316)Tennis">Tennis</option>
        <option value="(1593328)Water Sports">Water Sports</option>
    </select><br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: Does any PHP work? What if you add `phpinfo();` just before `?>`?

Comment: It does work, for a while I had it posting "Done!" just to make sure the php is in fact working- it is. When I had the PHP part in another file, it would tell me that the item I was attempting to access via post- and I did check for spelling errors, going so far as to copy paste the name value- didn't exist. I thought it was a "not sending properly" between files problem, which was why I moved it to processing on the same page, but that's obviously not working. TT^TT

Comment: try to dump your `$_REQUEST` variable. If not helps, check your 'Net' tab using browser developers function.

Comment: @MarianSabo still gave me array(0) { }. Forgive me for asking, how do I check the Net tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RedRazor's answer is not a solution. The PHP interpreter resets the quotes inside of the php tags. This means that you can re-use the same quotes in the interpretation snippet.

This seems more like a PHP Storm issue, try to restart your PHP Storm server. I copied your code exactly to my machine and used PHP Storm built in server. With no modifications your code worked. I've attached some images of my setup.

Also you have to be running the PHP server to get `$_POST` requests, there is an icon to just open in the browser, which will work for many cases, but it will not work on requests like this due to their nature.

Here are some images of my setup:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: This is probably the solution, BUT I think I also have a permissions error. [Tue Oct 25 11:47:41 2016] Failed to listen on localhost:80 (reason: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

Comment: You will need to make sure that you have permission to bind to port 80. Perhaps something else is currently bound to port 80. You can assign it to something like 8080. You can technically assign it to any number within an unsigned 16-bit integer range (0-65535) as long as it is not currently bound to by another process.

Comment: Welp, I didn't get the "bad gate" page, but I'm still getting the good ol' array(0) { } as the answer. Meaning no post TTOTT

Comment: Make sure you are typing in `localhost:8080/` in the browser rather than using the buttons in PHP storm, I think they take you to some other random port.

Comment: OKAY
So it was a mixture of this issue and making sure I have the right URL- I was doing something strange within PHPStorm that had never caused me issue before because I had never been trying to access Post data before from my version of the localhost, which wasn't running off of a server. Once I was accessing the script on localhost:8080/ it began working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that there is no conflict between quotation marks ("")

Instead of

```
   <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

Try

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
```

Comment: Nope. I still got array(0) { } as my var_dump. But I do actually see what you mean now- that was probably going to cause an issue at some point, thank you.

Comment: Not necessarily. I can test it on a single page here (your code) and get output to the array dump on the bottom.

Comment: Please var_dump(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])).

Comment: string(24) "/CS_NewListing/index.php" is what I got. Otherwise nothing else. I also tried echoing out one of the fields- echo $_POST["modelnumber"] instead of the var_dump, but that still gave me a fat load of nothing.

Comment: Is it possible this is a permissions thing? Though that doesn't make a whole lot of sense, as this isn't the only form script running on the server that's submitting data. Those would have to break as well.